# ASP.NET Regular Expression number range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to create a regular expression that accepts any value between 1 to 350,000 and not anything more.

Currently I have this:

```
^([1-9](\d){0,4}([.](\d){1,2})?|350000([.](0){1,2})?)?$
```

It satisfies the condition of 350000. Anything in the range of 100,000 to 350,000 throws the error message which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
^((\d{1,5})|([1-2]\d{5})|([3][0-4]\d{4}))(\.\d{1,2})?$|^(350000)(\.(0){1,2})?$
```

Comment: I was paying more attention to the text of your question than the expression you provided and didn't notice the optional decimal values.  I've updated the answer to provide those in case you're interested.